# Trying to read data into an array from a file using a while loop. Also have to check to make sure the first and only value is not -1

Tags: c++, arrays

I intended for it to display the values read in from the file but it just ends after I enter the file path.

Input file contains:

5658845 40 8

4520125 25.25 9.25

7895122 30 10.50

8777541 10 12

8451277 50 10.20

1302850 35.20 7.50

-1

[Screenshot of the program when it's run. Yes that is the correct file path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhU5v.png)

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 20;

int read(long int[], double[], double[]);


int main()
{
    int checkRead;              //Define int variable to check if read was successfully executed
    long int empId[SIZE];       //Define employee id array
    double hours[SIZE];         //Define hours worked array
    double payRate[SIZE];       //Define pay rate array
    double wages[SIZE];         //Define wages array
    ofstream outfile;           //Define output file


    cout << setw(30) << "PAYROLL PROCESSING" << endl << endl;      //Program header

    checkRead = read(empId, hours, payRate);
    if (checkRead = -1)
        return 0;

    for (int c = 0; c < SIZE; c++)
        cout << empId[c] << " " << hours[c] << " " << payRate[c] << endl;

    return 0;
}

int read(long int id[], double hrs[], double rate[])    //Function to read data from file
{
    int count = 0;
    long int tempId = 0;
    ifstream infile;                                    //Define input file
    string fileIn;                                      //Define file name
    cout << "Enter the name of the input file: ";       //Prompt for input file name
    cin >> fileIn;                                      //Read input file name
    infile.open(fileIn);                                //Open input file

    if (infile.fail())      //check to see if input file failed to open
    {
        cout << "Error. Invalid file path" << endl;     //if input file failed to open print error message
        return -1;      //return -1 to read
    }
    while (tempId >= 0 && count < SIZE)
    {
        infile >> id[count] >> hrs[count] >> rate[count];
        tempId = id[count];
        if (count = 0 && tempId < 0)
        {
            cout << "Error. This file contains no data" << endl;
            return -1;
        }
        count++;
    }

    infile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `if (checkRead == -1)`, not `if (checkRead = -1)`, `if (checkRead = -1)` is always true in your case...

```
checkRead = read(empId, hours, payRate);
if (checkRead = -1) // should be if (checkRead == -1)
    return 0;

for (int c = 0; c < SIZE; c++)
    cout << empId[c] << " " << hours[c] << " " << payRate[c] << endl;
```

And `if (count = 0 && tempId < 0)` should be `if (count == 0 && tempId < 0)`:

```
while (tempId >= 0 && count < SIZE)
{
    infile >> id[count] >> hrs[count] >> rate[count];
    tempId = id[count];
    if (count = 0 && tempId < 0) // should be if (count == 0 && tempId < 0)
    {
        cout << "Error. This file contains no data" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I totally forgot about the == and it was returning 0 to main thus ending the program. I got it working now and it's displaying a bunch of crazy numbers at the end but I'm sure I'll figure it out. Thanks again for your help.